# Edit Suggestion disappeared

Tags: support, editing

An hour or so ago I suggested an edit for [this question about heat-conductance in diamonds](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45910/diamond-excellent-heat-conductor-due-to-phonons-explain). When I now browse to said question, I don’t see the block ‘your edit is being reviewed’ anymore, nor does it appear in [the list of my suggestions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12808/claudius?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) where it definitely was listed half an hour ago.

What happened to this suggestion?

Comment: Hm... I remember looking at that question, and possibly at your suggested edit, but I don't know why there wouldn't be a record of it.

Comment: I took the liberty to suggest a second edit, roughly similar to the one I first suggested. I can recall an edit suggestion disappearing a few weeks ago, but unfortunately cannot remember which and where.

Comment: Nice edit. I approved the one that was pending, but have no idea what happened to the other...

Comment: Thank you :-). I will try to write it off as either a memory or computer glitch on my side, but it still looks rather strange.